# Magento 2 REST API Products - limit which custom_attributes returned

Tags: magento2, collection, rest-api

There can be a lot of custom attributes for a product and some have very long values. Is there a way to filter the responses to include just one specific `attribute_code` value?

Note: this is not talking about filtering the Products returned, I have other criteria to filter the top level products, I just don't want to return the full `custom_attributes` array, but rather something like this in SQL `SELECT * FROM custom_attributes WHERE attribute_code = 'some value'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out how to do this.

It seems Magento treats the `custom_attributes` collection properties (`attribute_codes`) as field names directly, so you can search by them and limit their results in the 'fields`list by referring to the`attribute_code` value directly.

Let's take a look at the following `attribute_code` within `custom_attributes` example:

```
{
   "attribute_code": "color",
   "value": "red"
}
```

To filter the products to include only those that have a `custom_attribute` of `color = red`, you can do this:

```
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=color
&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=red
&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq
```

And further, to limit the collection of `custom_attributes` to only return the `color` custom attribute, include it in the list of `fields`, like this (specifically the `custom_attributes[color]` part, but showing it within the context of including some other fields as you normally would):

```
items[id,sku,name,custom_attributes[color]]
```

If you want more than one attribute, list them via a comma separated list, like so:

```
custom_attributes[color,size]
```

The only strange thing about this, is that it is wrapping the attribute_code within a higher level parent, `12` in this case...which I think is the Attribute Id.

```
"custom_attributes": {
   "12": {
            "attribute_code": "ship_length",
            "value": "11.0000"
         }
    }
```